# How can I make a Kinetic.Line fire an event like the other Kinetic shapes?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

You can interact with this code [here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GeekStocks/bfVwE/)

In the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GeekStocks/bfVwE/) you can see that I have made a flag (Kinetic.Rect) on a flagpole (Kinetic.Line).  I desire to fire an event when the user moves the mouse over any portion of the flag or flagpole.  In prior attempts I have attached event handlers to each shape individually, only to learn that Kinetic.Line does not fire events.

In this latest attempt I added the shapes to a group and attached the handler to the group thinking this would solve the issue: it does not.

Is there any way to achieve the desired behavior?  Thank you, and remember to press F12 to see the handler's console messages.

```
var handler = function(e) {
    console.log("Event fired.");
};

var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'testBlock',
    width: 200,
    height: 200
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var group = new Kinetic.Group();

var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 75,
    y: 10,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'silver',
});

line = new Kinetic.Line({
    points: [
        {x: 125, y: 10},
        {x: 125, y: 160},
    ],
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 1
});

// add the shapes to the group
group.add(rect);
group.add(line);

// event handler for the group
group.on("mouseover", handler);

// add the group to the layer
layer.add(group);

// add the layer to the stage
stage.add(layer);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kinetic.Line's have trouble with events when the stroke is too small, you can see this evident with any line with stroke < 3px.

This was the response I got from Eric Rowell (creator of KineticJS):

> yep, KineticJS ignores the anti-aliased pixels. If you're drawing a 1px diagonal line, and you want it to be detectable, you need to create a custom hit function to define the hit region. You probably will want to create a hit region that's a line which is about 5px thick or so. Here's an example on creating custom hit regions:
>
> http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-custom-hit-function-tutorial/

So in addition to Ani's answer, you can also use the `drawHitFunc` property to make a custom hit region for the line that is thicker than the actual line:

```
    line = new Kinetic.Line({
        points: [
            {x: 125, y: 10},
            {x: 125, y: 160},
        ],
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 1,
        drawHitFunc: function(canvas) {
            var x1=this.getPoints()[0].x;
            var x2=this.getPoints()[1].x;
            var y1=this.getPoints()[0].y;
            var y2=this.getPoints()[1].y;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = 1;
            ctx.moveTo(x1-3,y1-3);
            ctx.lineTo(x1-3,y2+3);
            ctx.lineTo(x2+3,y2+3);
            ctx.lineTo(x2+3,y1-3);
            ctx.closePath();
            canvas.fillStroke(this);
        }
    });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/yJzN9/)

Comment: So the issue then is NOT that a line cannot fire events (it can), but that the line's "hit region" is so small that the mouseover event is often not hit.  Interesting.  Excellent answer; Eric's comments and a link to the correct tutorial are a real plus.  Thank you for posting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aplus1/bfVwE/6/)
I'm using `Kinetic.Rect` with `width=1` and `height=` y2-y1 of your line.

```
line = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 125, y: 10,
        width: 1, height: 150,    
    fill: 'black',
});
```

Comment: I tried your fiddle and while I did get events to fire, it was "hit or miss" (pardon the pun!).  If I moved the mouse back and forth across the flagpole, only about half of the events registered.  The answer from @projeqht addresses the root cause of the misses.  Use of the drawHitFunc is the right way to go here, but thank you for posting an interesting work-around.